# Linking GLTranR and SeegmentValue by SubID in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to link GLTranR to SegmentValue by a first segment of subaccount matching SegmentValue.Value.

GLTranR.SubID looks like 'CORP000000000000', yet =CStr( [GLTranR.SubID] ) returns 535.

Including a formula =Substring( [GLTranR.OrigSubID], 1, 4 ) into Results Grid causes an error:
"Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function."

I saw some references to a field SubCd, yet it does not show up under GlTranR.

SegmentValue has SegmentID = 1 for Department, and DimensionID = SUBACCOUNT.

Any ideas how to make this linkage between GLTranR and SegmentValues will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The link between GLTranR and SegmentValue has to be done through a separate table Sub.

Sub is linked to GLTranR by GLTranR.SubID equals Sub.SubID, and then

Sub is linked to SegmentValue by =Substring( [Sub.SubCD], 1, 4 ) equals SegmentValue.Value